# hash table does not count values correctly

Tags: java, hashtable

Here, i'm trying to implement a chaining hash table. In here when I enter a same key, it joins with existing key and adds one to value. The problem that I get is when I print final table it gives wrong values. Every time there is a key along, while other same keys are joining together.

Insert Function is coded as below.

```
 public void insert (String key, int value){

        int hashValue= generateHashValue(key); //find what bucket suits for each key


        if(table[hashValue] == null) {
            table[hashValue] = new HashTableLinked(key, value);//enter new key           
        }

        else{
            HashTableLinked entry = table[hashValue];
            boolean condition =false;

            while (entry.next!= null){

                if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {

                    entry.setValue(entry.getValue()+1);  //trying to add +1 for existing key 
                    condition = true;
                    break;
                }

                entry = entry.next;
            }
            if(!condition) {
                entry.next = new HashTableLinked(key, value);
            }        
        }


    }
```

The hashTableLinked Class is as below if necessary,

```
public class HashTableLinked {

   private String key;
     int value;
     HashTableLinked next;

   public HashTableLinked(String key,int value){
     this.key = key;
     this.value = value;
     this.next = null;

   public void setValue(int value) {
     this.value = value;
   }

   public String getKey() {
      return key;
   }
   public int getValue(){
     return value;
  }
}
```

when I enter the input line as this which contains 5 "the"s

```
We the People the the the of freedom in Order to form the
```

the output is

```
Bucket 9 : the  4 
           the  1
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Is there any reason for implementing your own hash table instead of using Java's?

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to guess what's the problem if there is not enough code to be run, for example method generateHashValue(key) is not described here. The same applies to {table} property.

Comment: I thought the other part of the code is unnecessary.. because it contains more lines..@Kamil...

Comment: This is some kind of a homework..but it is not what you think as homework :) @JPRLCol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the check already done in the if statement:

```
while (entry.next!= null) {
```

should be

```
while (entry != null) {
```

You could eliminate the if statement, taking care of entry being null after the loop.

```
        HashTableLinked entry = table[hashValue];
        boolean found = false;
        HashTableLinked priorEntry = null;
        while (entry != null) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                entry.setValue(entry.getValue() + 1);  //trying to add +1 for existing key 
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            priorEntry = entry;
            entry = entry.next;
        }
        if (!found) {
            if (priorEntry == null) {
                table[hashValue] = new HashTableLinked(key, value);
            } else {
                priorEntry.next = new HashTableLinked(key, value);
            }
        }
```

Indeed awkward. A bit better would be to insert in front:

```
        boolean found = false;
        for (HashTableLinked entry = table[hashValue]; entry != null; entry = entry.next) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                entry.setValue(entry.getValue() + 1);  // trying to add 1 for existing key 
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            HashTableLinked added = new HashTableLinked(key, value);
            added.next = table[hashValue];
            table[hashValue] = added;
        }
```

Comment: No need of priorEntry to find the last element to add after.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked..  :) ..why is always better to insert  front? to reduce time?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your loop:

```
//This will be the first entry for that bucket
HashTableLinked entry = table[hashValue];
boolean condition =false;

//What happens when the bucket only contains one entry? The loop won't get executed
while (entry.next!= null){
  if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
    entry.setValue(entry.getValue()+1);  //trying to add +1 for existing key 
    condition = true;
    break;
  }
  entry = entry.next;
}

//If the loop doesn't get executed, condition will be false
if(!condition) {
  entry.next = new HashTableLinked(key, value);
}
```

This means that when you add an identical key your code will create a new entry and from then on the original entry will be updated in the loop.

What you want is to check whether `entry` itself is null or not, not whether there is a next entry.

Btw, this should have been easy to spot by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: @roch.p read carefully: the loop executes when you add the key a 3rd time. The first time you'll be in the `if(table[hashValue] == null)` branch, the second time `while (entry.next!= null)` won't do a single iteration as `entry.next` will be null immediately. That's why you get 2 entries and why all but one (the second) counts are added to the first entry.